# Will Google relate keywords to those listed?

Tags: seo

Our company offers service in all of the surrounding areas but I don't want to "keyword hoard" so I can't list each location and each type of service offered there in the meta keywords.

But, we do have our locations and service areas listed on the actual pages. So then if I were to list our services only in the meta area, would Google/SE automatically relate them to the locations shown on the page?

If not, what is the best strategy in covering these geographic areas with a list of our keywords without being penalized for listing out every location attached to every keyword we want to rank for?

Answer (score 1):

One way that I recommend is to collect customer testimonials from all the towns and regions that you service.   Then you can have pages like:

> I used Joe's pluming service when my shower drain got clogged.   They came out at 8:00 on a Saturday night and were very professional.
>
> Sally Salverson, East Hampron, KT

Another way is to list delivery charges or response times for each place:

```
 East Hampron - $25 per truckload
 West Hampron - $45 per truckload
 Bahton - $30 per truckload
```

You have to find a way to use the place names in a natural way that is useful to users.  Google says that you should not

- [just make a list of cities with no other content](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2319706/Googles-Matt-Cutts-A-Little-Duplicate-Content-Wont-Hurt-Your-Rankings)
- [create a set of pages that are all the same but which have the city name changed](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en&ref_topic=6001971).